# material-expansionpanel-set seems not to work under a material-tab

Tags: angular-material, angular-dart

The problem is rather simple, see the template below:

```
<material-tab-panel>
  <material-tab label="test">
    <material-expansionpanel-set>
      <material-expansionpanel name="panel 1">
        Test 1
      </material-expansionpanel>
      <material-expansionpanel name="panel 2">
        Test 2
      </material-expansionpanel>
    </material-expansionpanel-set>
  </material-tab>
</material-tab-panel>
```

The Dartium browser renders nothing. If I remove the surrounding material-tab-panel and material-tab the expansion-panels are rendered with the expected accordion behavior. In reverse without the expensionpanel-set the tab is rendered correctly. It seems that the combination causes the problem.
Compiling to JavaScript does not change this outcome.

Comment: I have sent this issue to github.com/dart-lang/angular2_components: <https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2_components/issues/54>. 
The next release is supposed to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed in v0.4.0-alpha of the components.

See here https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2_components/releases/tag/v0.4.0-alpha

We hope to have this as a "gold" (non-alpha) release soon!